# Is there some reason that os.popen() malfuntions on a 'whatis' query

Tags: python-3.x, linux, popen

I am writing a program targeted to Unix/Linux which goes through all the programs in an executables directory  (e.g., "/usr/bin"), and gathers statistics on the scripts found there.

To do this, I use os.popen() to issue two commands, which are crucial to the program.

Here is a sample of the code that should illustrate what I mean:

```py
os.chdir("/usr/bin")
programs = os.listdir()
for program in programs:

    command = 'file ' + program
    p = os.popen(command)
    line = p.readline()
    line = line.rstrip()
    progtype = line
    p.close()

    command = 'whatis ' + program  
    p = os.popen(command)
    line = p.readline()
    line = line.rstrip()
    what = line
    p.close()
```

Now you can see that the os.popen() command is used for two shell commands, 'file' and 'whatis'. The first, using the 'file' command works as it should. I can use the output of the command by reading one line from filehandle "p", as in

```py
p=os.popen('file ssh')
```

I can store the output is a string variable to use later.

The second command, with "whatis" + program name, doesn't behave this way. upon the issuance of the statement:

```py
p=os.popen('whatis ssh')
```

The result of the command appears immediately on the screen, and doesn't seem to be available for use in a string variable, or any variable.

Has anyone else had this experience?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing. In an interactive python session and using string literals rather than the loop I get `>>> line
'ssh (1)              - OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)'`

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure it's regular output and not an error message (as those go to `stderr` instead of `stdout`)?

Comment: Right, What @Selcuk was suggesting ... a `command = 'whatis yplan'` renders to screen,  `>>> yplan: nothing appropriate.`  because there's no man-pages for it.